# margin-top:100%; goes far outside of containing element

Tags: css

Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JH4Ew/1/. I want align  `<p class="email">` to the bottom. I thought if I put

```
margin-top:100%;
```

it means 100% from height of the parent element. On the fiddle seems more then 100% of height. How to do this in right way?

PS I have updated the fiddle to right content, previous wasn't updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to align the paragraph to the bottom of the div:

```
#opening4 {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
.email{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JH4Ew/1/)**

By positioning the div relatively it allows you to set the position on the email paragraph absolutely, and by setting the bottom to zero, it will remain at the bottom of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position: relative` from the parent if you want it to be at the bottom of the window:

http://jsfiddle.net/2VyCj/1/

Answer (score 1):

Margin is distance from sibling elements, not the distance from the inside of the parent.